# How to determine version of an add-in from MS Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I have created a MS Word add-in using C#/VSTO.  When building with Visual Studio I set the version number for each published build.  Is there a way for the users to find the build version of the add-in from Word (Office 365) so that they can determine if they are running the newest version?  I can see that the add-in is installed under Options->Add-ins, but it doesn't list the version.  Worst case I can add something to the Ribbon to display it but I'm hoping there is an easier way.  Thanks!

Comment: Up to you to explore and document what is possible before asking your question. Did you look at what Word's object model have to offer and rule those options out? You didn't say which of the various settings in your add-in Project/Assembly you tried to change - for example assembly name, Assembly Information->Title, Description, Product. AFAICS only one of those settings is displayed in Word's Add-In options, but I cannot guarantee I have looked at them all. i.e. it seems that by changing one of those names, however inconvenient that is, you can achieve what you need.

Comment: @yokki - I'm not looking to retrieve the version from my application.  I'm trying to determine if Word has an option that people who are not SW developers can use to list the published versions of installed add-ins.

Comment: That's not a programming question, which is what this site is about. It's a  question to do with the Word application, which you could perhaps ask on SuperUser, for example.

Comment: You could write it to the "Description" that's visible under File/Options/Add-ins. Other than that, no.

Comment: Why not add an "About" or "Help" dialog box to your addin?